# render page title using jsf 2

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

is there any way to include the page's title inside an `f:ajax` tag, so that its content is also updated at run time?
currently my f:ajax tag looks like this -

```
<f:ajax render="@form">
```

i tried to add an id to the h:head tag, and add that id to the 'render' property of the f:ajax tag, but if i do so i get an error when the page loads -

```
<f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'pageHead' - cannot locate it in the context of the component B1
```

cheers,
eRez

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question. I think there is no such command in render of ajax (like @form) to re-render the page title. What you can do is to wrap `<title>` with `<h:form>` or other "grouping" component (eg. `h:panelGroup` as Daniel said) like this :

```
    <h:form id="titleForm">
        <title>#{fooBean.fooTitle}</title>
    </h:form>
```

And then call ajax update eg. with button :

```
        <h:commandButton immediate="true" value="Change title">
            <f:ajax event="click" render=":titleForm"  listener="#{fooBean.changeTitle}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
```

Bean:

```
  private String fooTitle;

  public void changeTitle() {
        this.fooTitle= "updatedTitle";
  }
// getter/setter
```

I don't know what else could you do, this should work. So wrap your `title` with `<h:form id="...">` and then render it from ajax.

Comment: there is "@all" but does nothing special than "@form"

Comment: @Ravi Yes I know that there is "@all". I just wanted to say there is no tag related to rendering the page title.

Comment: You don't have to wrap the tile with <h:form , a simple <h:panelGroup id="titleWrapperID"> will be enough... cause anyway the h:commandButton will be wrapped in its form

Comment: @Daniel Just to clarify, my intent was to show wrapping with some component. The fact I chose form has nothing to do with commandButton - which is there just for example - it just popped in my head as first thing. You are right about h:panelGroup, it's enough. Thank you for comment I will edit answer

Comment: @Fallup I know, I wasn't criticizing you :)

Comment: Let me object that the rendered html from `h:form` and `h:panelGroup` inside the head section of a page are not valid html. See [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566059/execute-javascript-after-ajax-update) for a alternative approach using `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent`.